# MS Access form's record set is not updated if I do not close the form?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I am using this code to insert data to a table from a continuous form.
on click event:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
    Do Until rs.EOF = True
        If rs!Cont_Selct = True Then
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL "insert into tbl_favconn (fav_name,cont_id) values('" & Me.txtGroupSrch & "','" & rs!Cont_id & "' )"
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
            rs.Edit
            rs!Cont_Selct = False
            rs.Update
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    MsgBox "done"
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

When I open the form for first time it works fine, but when I try to select 
other contacts it is not accepting, so I must close the form and reopen it to
select other contacts to add them.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You reset `Cont_Selct` for all records of the form, so what could you possibly select?

Comment: Thanks for replay Gustav, I mean after re-selecting manually its not accepting to perform the code , so i must close the form and reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer by the way .

its to bring records in front like this:

before beginning the loop.

```
rs.movefirst

If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
'' rest of the code
```